# Faut-il le subjonctif dans la phrase « malgré [le fait] qu'ils refusaient d'y croire »

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, indicatif

Je sais que « le fait que » n'exige pas toujours le subjonctif, mais il me semble que presque tous les usages de cette expression parmi les francophones sont employés dans ce mode. Alors pourquoi « refusaient » n’est-il pas au subjonctif (refuse, ait refusé, refusât, ou eût refusé)?

Comment: Probablement par ce que 'ils refusaient d'y croire' est un événement réél et non hypothétique. Par exemple, je pense que votre phrase 'mais il me semble que ... sont employés' devrait être 'mais il me semble que ... soient employés'.

Comment: « … malgré le fait qu'ils refusaient d'y croire *[maintenant]* », « … malgré le fait  qu'ils refusassent d'y croire *[à l'époque (du fait)]* » subjonctif soutenu, voire précieux ; plus de contexte serait bénéfique pour discerner la règle à utiliser.

Comment: @vc74 Il me semble que l'indicatif **est** l'usage après *il me semble que* bien qu'il semble que l'indicatif **soit** l'usage après *il semble que*.

Answer (score 1):

Il faut bien le subjonctif après les expressions de concession comme *bien que* ou *malgré que*, et ses dérivés comme *malgré le fait que*.

En revanche, *malgré que* est devenu très archaïque est est considéré aujourd'hui comme une erreur, et ainsi votre phrase ne me semble pas correcte.

Normalement *malgré*, aujourd'hui, est uniquement suivi d'un nom, sinon on utilise plutôt *bien que.*

Donc je dirais plutôt "Malgré leur refus d'y croire" (ce qui allège la structure) ou "Bien qu'ils refusaient d'y croire".

Comment: C'est juste, mais vous n'expliquez pas pourquoi "refusaient" n'est pas au subjonctif justement (y compris avec *Bien que*).

Comment: C'est vrai! Normalement on devrait utiliser l'imparfait du subjonctif dans ce cas: "Bien qu'ils refusassent d'y croire", mais ce mode est devenu très archaïque et plus ou moins tombé dans l'oubli, et il est maintenant tout à fait correct et normal d'utiliser l'imparfait de l'indicatif.

Comment: Oui l'imparfait du subjonctif est vraiment vieillot, mais l'usage serait plutôt d'utiliser le subjonctif présent plutôt que de passer à l'indicatif, non?